# where is Azure DevOps build artifact stored

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

I am attempting to create a CI pipeline for a WCF project. I got the CI to successfully run but cannot determine where to look for the artifact. My intent is to have the CI pipeline publish this artifact in Azure and then have the CD pipeline run transformations on config files. Ultimately, we want to take that output and store it in blob storage (that will probably be another post since the WCF site is for an API).

I also realize that I really do not want to zip the artifact since I will need to transform it anyway.

Here are my questions:

1. Where is the container that the artifact 'drop' is published to?
2. How would I publish the site to the container without making it a single file.

Thanks

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- release/2021-June-CI

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**./*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '******************************' # private nuget package masked

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

# todo - unit tests do not exist yet
#- task: VSTest@2
#  inputs:
#    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
#    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find your artifacts here:

[image]

You got single file because you have in VSBuild `/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true`

Also you may consider using a newer task [`Publish Pipeline Artifact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). If not please check `DownloadBuildArtifacts` task [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: Thanks @krzysztof-madej. I know about the /p:PackageAsSingleFile being false. The real question is if there is an impact on the /p:PackageLocation parameter. I will try the newer task as well